# Qual seria o tamanho padrão para criar botões no menu de websites, em diferentes resoluções?

Tags: webdesign, gui

Gostaria de ter uma ideia do tamanho de botões para websites em suas respectivas resoluções, como botões do menu, botões de redes-sociais, botões de perguntas, entre outros...

Tem algum site de informação sobre esse tema?

Comment: Que eu saiba, não há padrão para isso. Depende do design do site.

Comment: Tem este artigo que dá para ter uma idéia. http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/21/finger-friendly-design-ideal-mobile-touchscreen-target-sizes/

Comment: Obrigada, Tony!!

Answer (score 2):

Não existe um "padrão" de tamanhos. O que existe são estudos e recomendações, até porque variações de design entre sites comportam vários tipos de tamanhos e formas de botões.

Um [artigo muito bom](http://ergo.human.cornell.edu/ahtutorials/interface.html), o qual traduzo aqui, traz várias linhas guia para o desenvolvimento de interfaces:

### Consistência ("princípio da menor surpresa")

- Certos aspectos de uma interface deve se comportar de forma consistente em todos os momentos para todas as telas;
- Terminologia deve ser consistente entre telas;
- Ícones deve ser consistente entre telas;
- Cores devem ser consistentes entre telas de função semelhante;

### Simplicidade

- Quebre tarefas complexas em tarefas mais simples;
- Quebre sequências longas em etapas separadas;
- Mantenha tarefas fáceis, usando ícones, palavras, etc.;
- Use ícones / objetos que são familiares ao usuário;

### Limitações de memória humana

- Organize as informações em um pequeno número de "pedaços";
- Tente criar seqüências lineares curtas de tarefas;
- Não faça piscar informações importantes na tela por períodos consideráveis;
- Organize os campos de dados para corresponder as expectativas dos usuários, ou para organizar a entrada do usuário (por exemplo, números de telefone de formatação automática);
- Forneça pistas auxiliares / navegação para o usuário saber onde eles estão no software ou em que fase eles estão em uma operação;
- Forneça lembretes ou avisos conforme apropriado;
- Forneça feedback contínuo sobre o que é e / ou apenas aconteceu;
- Permita que os usuários reconheçam em vez de recordar informações;
- Minimize a trabalhar cargas de memória, limitando a duração das sequências e quantidade de informação - evitar ícone mania.

### Direcionamento Cognitivo

- Minimize as transformações mentais de informação (por exemplo, usando "Ctrl + Shift + esc +8' para recuar um parágrafo);
- Use ícones significativos / letras;
- Use pistas visuais adequadas, como setas de direção;
- Use metáforas 'do mundo real', sempre que possível (por exemplo, metáfora da mesa de trabalho, metáfora da pasta, metáfora da lata de lixo, etc);

### Feedback

- Forneça feedback informativo nos pontos apropriados;
- Forneça feedback adequado articulatório - feedback que confirma a operação física que você fez (por exemplo, digitei 'ajuda' e 'help' aparecer na tela). Isto inclui todas as formas de comentários, como feedback auditivo (por exemplo, emite um sinal sonoro do sistema, clique do mouse, clica-chave, etc);
- Forneça feedback com semântica apropriada - feedback que confirma a intenção de uma ação (por exemplo, com destaque para um item a ser escolhido de uma lista);
- Forneça indicadores de status apropriados para mostrar ao usuário o progresso com uma operação longa (por exemplo, a barra de cópia ao copiar arquivos, um ícone de ampulheta quando um processo está sendo executado, etc);

### Mensagens do sistema

- Forneça texto centrado no usuário em mensagens (por exemplo, "houve um problema em copiar o arquivo para o seu disco" ao invés de "erro de execução 159");
- Evite mensagens ambíguas (por exemplo, presisone 'qualquer' tecla para continuar - não há 'qualquer' chave e não há necessidade de apertar uma tecla, reformular a dizer "pressione a tecla Enter para continuar);
- Evite o uso de mensagens ameaçadoras ou alarmantes (por exemplo, erro fatal, execute abortado, matar trabalho, erro catastrófico);
- Use palavras específicas, construtivas em mensagens de erro (por exemplo, evitar mensagens gerais, tais como "entrada inválida" e de uso específicos, tais como "Por favor, insira o seu nome");
- Faça o sistema "assumir a culpa" por erros (por exemplo, "o comando ilegal" versus "comando não reconhecido")

### Antropomorfização

- Não antropomorfizar (ou seja, não atribuir características humanas a objetos) - evitar a mensagens do seu computador como por exemplo "Tenha um bom dia";

### Modalidade

- Use modos cautelosamente - um modo é um estado onde a interface que o usuário faz tem ações diferentes do que em outros estados (por exemplo, mudando a forma do cursor podem indicar se o usuário está em um modo de edição ou um modo de navegação);
- Minimize os modos de preferência, modos de preferência especialmente irreversíveis - um modo preventivo é aquele em que o usuário deve completar uma tarefa antes de prosseguir para a próxima. Em um modo preventivo outras funções do software são inacessíveis (por exemplo, caixas de diálogo para salvar arquivos);
- Torne as ações do usuário facilmente reversíveis - use 'desfazer' comandos, mas usá-los com moderação;
- Permita rotas de escape de operações;

### Atenção

- Use técnicas chamam a atenção com cautela (por exemplo, evitar o uso excessivo 'pisca' em páginas da web, exibindo mensagens, 'você tem mail', cores fortes, etc);
- Não use mais de 4 diferentes tamanhos de fonte por tela;
- Usar fonte com ou sem serifa apropriadamente de acordo com a situação visual;
- Não use todas as letras maiúsculas - uso e mistura letras maiúsculas / minúsculas;
- Não use excessivamente áudio ou vídeo;
- Usar cores de forma adequada e fazer uso de expectativas (por exemplo, não tem um botão OK de cor vermelha (usar verde para OK), amarelo para cautela e vermelho para 'perigo' ou 'pare');
- Não use mais de 4 cores diferentes em uma tela;
- Não use azul para texto (difícil de ler), o azul é uma boa cor de fundo;
- Não colocar texto vermelho em um fundo azul (péssimo para daltônicos);
- Utilize combinações de cores de contraste;
- Usar cores de forma consistente;
- Usar apenas 2 níveis de intensidade em uma única tela;
- Use sublinhado, negrito, vídeo inverso ou outros marcadores com moderação;
- Em telas de texto não use mais de 3 fontes em uma única tela;

### Problemas de exibição

- Manter exibição inércia - certifique-se a tela muda pouco de uma tela para a próxima tarefa dentro de uma situação funcional;
- Organize a complexidade da tela;
- Elimine informações desnecessárias;
- Use frases concisas, sem ambiguidade, para instruções e mensagens;
- Use ícones fáceis de reconhecer;
- use um layout de tela equilibrado - não colocar muita informação na parte superior da tela - para tentar equilibrar a informação em cada quadrante da tela;
- Use a abundância de "espaço branco" em torno de blocos de texto - utilize pelo menos 50% de espaço em branco para as telas de texto;
- Agrupe informações logicamente;
- Estruture a informação em vez de apenas apresentar um formato narrativo (compreensão pode ser 40% mais rápido para um formato estruturado);

### Diferenças individuais

- Acomode diferenças individuais na experiência do usuário (desde o iniciante até o alfabetizado computador)
- Acomode as preferências do usuário, permitindo algum grau de personalização de layout de tela, aparência, ícones etc
- Permita formas alternativas para os comandos (por exemplo, através de combinações da seleção de teclas de menu);

Answer (score 0):

Até onde eu saiba, não tem um tamanho padronizado, irá depender mesmo do seu design.

Muitas vezes o botão não é nem um botão em si, mas sim uma palavra.
Essas coisas dependem muito de onde você quer chegar.

Recomendo você presquisar por palavras como `User Xperience`, `User Interface`, `User Design` assim você poderá enteder melhor quais os padroes que a Web utiliza.

O próprio StackExchange tem um forum dedicado somente a esse assunto, é o

**[UX StackExchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buttons)**

Comment: Obrigada, Igor!